# ChildProcessError for image moderation firebase function

Tags: firebase, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying implement image moderation code to remove adult or violent content as given here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/generate-thumbnail

But every time i'm getting this error:

```
ChildProcessError: Command failed: convert /tmp/test folder/yes.jpg -channel RGBA -blur 0x8 /tmp/test folder/yes.jpg
convert: unable to open image `/tmp/test': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2712.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert: unable to open image `folder/yes.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2712.
convert: unable to open image `/tmp/test': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2712.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert: no images defined `folder/yes.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.
 `convert /tmp/test folder/yes.jpg -channel RGBA -blur 0x8 /tmp/test folder/yes.jpg` (exited with error code 1)
    at callback (/user_code/node_modules/child-process-promise/lib/index.js:33:27)
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:213:5)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
```

due to this line:

```
// Blur the image using ImageMagick.
    return exec(`convert ${tempLocalFile} -channel RGBA -blur 0x8 ${tempLocalFile}`);
```

And one more help what is best way to moderate video instead of image, i.e. if i want to check if video uploaded is not offensive(adult or violent).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks fmw42 for help, it was silly mistake. Issue in command is with whitespaces only, try avoiding spaces in folder name. Anyway if you have handle command carefully like:

```
return exec(`convert "${tempLocalFile}" -channel RGBA -blur 0x8 "${tempLocalFile}"`);
```

Comment: FYI the sample has been updated and uses `spawn` instead: `return spawn('convert', [tempLocalFile, '-thumbnail', \`${THUMB_MAX_WIDTH}x${THUMB_MAX_HEIGHT}>\`, tempLocalThumbFile], {capture: ['stdout', 'stderr']});`

Answer (score 1):

You have:

> convert /tmp/test folder/yes.jpg -channel RGBA -blur 0x8 /tmp/test folder/yes.jpg

/tmp/test is there in two places and is just a path. ImageMagick will not like a path without an image file. You already have the input and output files with path as folder/yes.jpg. This is why you get

> unable to open image `/tmp/test': No such file or directory

Perhaps you meant

```
convert /tmp/test/folder/yes.jpg -channel RGBA -blur 0x8 /tmp/test/folder/yes.jpg
```

or

```
convert /tmp/test/yes.jpg -channel RGBA -blur 0x8 /tmp/test/yes.jpg
```

or

```
convert folder/yes.jpg -channel RGBA -blur 0x8 folder/yes.jpg
```

So it looks like your variable replacement or code with variables is incorrect.

P.S. Do you really want to blur the alpha channel? Using -channel RGBA will do so. If you do not want to blur the alpha channel, then use -channel RGB. You may also get a different result without -channel RGBA.

Comment: I tried all the three mentioned way but no success. Moreover i guess code is correct cause it is mentioned in firebase documentation too: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/06/content-moderation-with-cloud-functions.html   And before bluring image is successfully downloaded as log says: The file has been downloaded to /tmp/test folder/yes.jpg

Comment: If your file has been indeed downloaded to The file has been downloaded to /tmp/test folder/yes.jpg, then you need to put quotes around the path to avoid issues with spaces. So use "/tmp/test folder/yes.jpg".  You must have a directory called test folder, with a space in it. I generally avoid spaces in directories or files. But you can use them if you quote the path

Comment: Yep it was issue with space only, Thanks though for help.