# Firebase Cloud Functions-ImageMagick CLI PDF to images

Tags: google-cloud-functions, imagemagick, firebase-storage, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to work with Firebase Cloud Functions, and ImageMagick, similar to how the [thumbnail demo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions#example_image_transformation) is done. By re-purposing the demo script, I want to execute a CLI command for [ImageMagick to split PDF pages to images](https://jdhao.github.io/2019/11/20/convert_pdf_to_image_imagemagick/#convert-all-pages-of-pdf-file-to-images).

> convert -density 150 presentation.pdf -quality 90 output-%3d.jpg

The snippet

```
exports.splitPdfPages = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
    const fileBucket = object.bucket; // The Storage bucket that contains the file.
    const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.
    const contentType = object.contentType; // File content type.
    const metageneration = object.metageneration; // Number of times metadata has been generated. New objects have a value of 1.

    // Download file from bucket.
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(fileBucket);
    const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
    const tempSplitImagesPath = tempFilePath.replace(".png", "_%3d.png");

    await bucket.file(filePath).download({destination: tempFilePath});
    console.log('PDF downloaded locally to', tempFilePath);

    // Generate split page images using ImageMagick.
    await spawn('convert', ['-density', '150', tempFilePath, '-quality', '90', tempSplitImagesPath]);
    console.log('pages split images created at', tempFilePath);

    ...
    // Uploading the split images.
    ...

    // Once the thumbnail has been uploaded delete the local file to free up disk space.
    return fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath);
});
```

Unfortunately, I'm encountering errors in the Cloud Functions log indicating the statement error

> ChildProcessError: `convert -density 150 /tmp/7eCxdDKqCb0rlYVw3AYf__foobar.pdf -quality 100 /tmp/7eCxdDKqCb0rlYVw3AYf__foobar_%3d.png` failed with code 1

I searched for [resolution to the error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44491554), but it only indicates that whitespaces are the main reason for the issue (which based on my statement doesn't have any). Invoking generateThumbnail function works properly, so I'm presuming its based on my changes

Am I missing something to properly call the ImageMagick command for converting PDF pages to image?

Looking forwad to hearing from you.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, limit yourself to a single question per post, or it might get closed as "needs focus".  Also, you should show the [complete minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the error.  There are too many variables here that we can't see.

Comment: @DougStevenson, I've updated the post and limited the question to ImageMagick CLI command in Cloud Functions. Thank you

Comment: @adjuremods Hi, did you find a solution?